# Trying to unserialize multiple arrays from file in PHP and can only get first line

Tags: php, serialization

So the code I'm using for unserializing is

```
<?php
$uline = unserialize(file_get_contents('phonebook.dat'));
?>
```

This works for the first line of the 'phonebook.dat' but the following lines are not being unserialized. The serialized format is as follows:

```
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"John Doe";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:11:"123 Main St";s:4:"City";s:5:"Dover";s:5:"State";s:2:"DE";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"19904";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1234";s:5:"Email";s:16:"john@example.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"Jane Doe";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:11:"123 Main St";s:4:"City";s:5:"Dover";s:5:"State";s:2:"DE";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"19904";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-5678";s:5:"Email";s:16:"jane@example.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:15:"Jonny Appleseed";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"1 Infinite Loop";s:4:"City";s:10:"Coopertino";s:5:"State";s:2:"CA";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"90201";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-9101";s:5:"Email";s:15:"jonny@apple.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:12:"Jack Sparrow";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"The Black Pearl";s:4:"City";s:17:"Cut Throat Island";s:5:"State";s:7:"Tortuga";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"00001";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1213";s:5:"Email";s:14:"jack@savvy.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:14:"Luke Skywalker";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"17 Jedi Council";s:4:"City";s:8:"Corasant";s:5:"State";s:2:"XX";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"99999";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1415";s:5:"Email";s:17:"luke@theforce.com";}
```

When I call the unserialize function I get the whole "John Doe" line as an output but can't figure out how to unserialize the rest of the file. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `file()`, which will read your file into an array. Then you want to unserialize each line individually.

Comment: https://eval.in/619750

Comment: @RobbieAverill this works if I paste the code into the php file but if i swap out the pasted serialized data for $contents = ('phonebook.dat'); I get a "Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 13 bytes". Know what this could be from?

Comment: @RobbieAverill nevermind forgot to add 'file_get_contents' before the ('phonebook.dat'); Thanks for the quick and simple help.

Comment: @RobbieAverill why not make this an answer? ;o)

Comment: hi, can anyone share this script? this url cannot be accessed, thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer courtesy of @RobbieAverill

https://eval.in/619750

Comment: hi, can anyone share this script? this url cannot be accessed, thank you